# binding wpf data templates to a hierarchy of view models

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a task as part of a larger story to set some properties in a view to be read-only.  These properties are part of a hierarchy of view-models and have been matched to views using data templates from an associated resources dictionary.  The data templates follow a very simple style, eg.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{ x:Type vm:MyTextFieldViewModel}">
    <v:TextFieldView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Using the example here, the view model MyTextFieldViewModel has a public property in a base class it uses for read-only (ie. IsReadOnly).  MyTextFieldViewModel is a child of the parent ViewModel that is being used here.

Is there a way in the data template to bind the IsReadOnly property of the MyTextFieldViewModel to its parent ViewModel? Or can I bind the matching property in the view to something outside of the view model specified in the data template (ie. the IsReadOnly property in the view get bound to the matching property in the parent ViewModel)?

Just to clarify a little - there isn't scope for doing this another way as this will involve a lot of extra work that we cannot justify at this point.  If we are going to do anything it's in the Data template.  We use Data templates elsewhere that bind ViewModels to controls (eg. to textboxes and comboboxes) where we do something similar to what I'm asking about here.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Perhaps you can make the `IsReadOnly` in your base class a dependency property, then in your datatemplate `<v:TextFieldView IsReadOnly="{Binding IsParentVmReadonly}" />`

Comment: Too broad. Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried already, and explain precisely what _specific_ problem you are having getting the results you want.

Comment: @PeterDuniho thanks for replying - I know the question was very broad and not so easy to answer.  I'll try to be more specific in future.

Comment: @mechanic thanks for replying.  Your suggestion looks very promising and I will investigate further.  If we're lucky any changes will have a small impact on other code and we'll be able to do it.  Otherwise we'll have to wait for another opportunity to refactor this area of code (but at least we'll be a bit better informed next time).  Many thanks.